# Next/Link bypassing skip-link on top of page

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, accessibility

Links using `Next/Link` are bypassing the skip-link component that is used for accessibility for keyboard users.

If we use regular `a` tags, the first `Tab` hit on the keyboard will focus on the skip-link component but if we are using `Next/Link`, then it will not focus on that, instead, it will focus on the second element, which in most cases is the logo.

This bug appears when the page is cached. So if you open incognito mode, all links will usually work for the first time as expected but when visited again, they will fail to work.

So basically, this will skip the first element on the next page that loads when I hit `Tab`,

```
<Link href="/search">
  <a aria-label="Search Page" className="header__search">
    Search
  </a>
</Link>
```

but this will as expected:

```
<a href="/search" aria-label="Search Page" className="header__search">
  Search
</a>
```

**Expected Behavior**

Whenever we change the page, the first `Tab` click should trigger a skip-link if it is available there.

**To Reproduce**

- Go to https://vercel.com/home
- Click on Integrations on the navigation bar.
- Hit the Tab key on the keyboard.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: No, you can't just paste a link to your non-working web site. Copy the code.

Comment: updated with the code. @Someone_who_likes_SE thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You should be providing workable code examples here, and not linking to your own website. This is to allow the question to remain and be useful after you have solved it and the link to your website no longer reflects the issue at the heart of the question.

Comment: It appears that you are incorrectly using the `<link>` element. The purpose of this element is not to create hyperlinks in the body of an HTML document, but rather to load external resources (like CSS) and to indicate relationships between documents. It also requires the use of the `rel` attribute. https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-link-element

Comment: @Josh sorry for not clearing it. That link is a Next.js feature not the regular link used for loading css